# Structure url_title

Tags: structure, entries, url-title

Is there an equivalent to `{exp:channel:entries url_title=""}` except that goes by the "`structure__uri`" that is defined in the Structure tab of an entry?

So that I can do like `{exp:channel:entries structure_url_title=""}`

Answer (score 3):

No, even though we use the same hooks as the Pages module EE has no parameter for that. Here are all of the available parameters for the channel tag: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#parameters

Comment: So how do you select entries based upon a structure url_title? If a user changes the Structure URL, the EE url_title does not get updated.. So what do you do when you're filtering channel:entries based on url_title?

Comment: If you're using Structure, you should stop using URL title all together IMO.

Comment: Then how do you cherry-pick an entry based off of the current URL? (Assuming we're not using `dynamic="yes"`)

Comment: Or, for instance.. How would you link to other pages that are managed by structure? If you have a `donate` page that is normally `/about-us/donate`, and you're linking to it by doing `{path="about-us/donate"}`... And then someone changes it to be `/contact-us/donate`... Then what? Then your links are broken. Am I just missing some important fact about Structure for linking/selecting entries?